# What is an alternative function for getBorderlines in Google App scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code running in Google App script that counts the cells that have a solid border (some cells have a dotted border) and returns that number.

I get the following error when I run the script:

```
TypeError: cell.getBorderlines is not a function
countSolidBorderedCells @ Code.gs:10
```

```
function countSolidBorderedCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, j + 1);
      var borders = cell.getBorderlines();
      if (borders.length > 0) {
        for (var k = 0; k < borders.length; k++) {
          if (borders[k].isSolid()) {
            count++;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("D22").setValue(count);
}
```

What should I replace that function with to make it work in Google App Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `getBorderLines()` for Google Sheets.  And unfortunately there is no method `getBorders()` that works for me.  So you have to use `getBorder()` for each cell and examine it.  I have a sample spreadsheet with random borders applied to different cells.

```
function getBorders() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let rows = range.getNumRows();
    let cols = range.getNumColumns();
    for( let i=0; i<rows; i++ ) {
      for( let j=0; j<cols; j++ ) {
        let cell = range.offset(i,j,1,1);
        let borders = cell.getBorder();
        if( borders ) {
          let border = borders.getLeft();
          if( border ) {
            if( border.getBorderStyle() ) console.log("range: "+cell.getA1Notation()+" left: "+border.getBorderStyle().toString());
          }
          border = borders.getRight();
          if( border ) {
            if( border.getBorderStyle() ) console.log("range: "+cell.getA1Notation()+" right: "+border.getBorderStyle().toString());
          }
          border = borders.getTop();
          if( border ) {
            if( border.getBorderStyle() ) console.log("range: "+cell.getA1Notation()+" top: "+border.getBorderStyle().toString());
          }
          border = borders.getBottom();
          if( border ) {
            if( border.getBorderStyle() ) console.log("range: "+cell.getA1Notation()+" bottom: "+border.getBorderStyle().toString());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
8:51:11 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: A2 left: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: A2 right: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: A2 top: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: A2 bottom: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: B4 left: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: B4 right: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: B4 top: SOLID
8:51:13 AM  Info    range: C5 right: DASHED
8:51:13 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Ideally, I'd like to output the number of cells with a border applied in cell D22 as an output, but I'm not quite sure from your example how I would do that.